# Drupal 8 Subtheme css not working in Edge

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-8

I have a drupal 8 site.
I have created a subtheme and altered the css of this subtheme.
My modification are showing and working fine in chrome and firefox but in internet explorer 11 and Edge it doesn work.
for instance this css code:

```
a,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
    color: #f4512c;
}
```

When I inspect the given element, i see the css properties of style.css being applied, but they are overridde by scaffolding.less..
How comes?

When I use !Important it is applied, but I would rather not use that !Important...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine, and should work on IE11 and Edge.

If you have opened the page with Edge before, the old stylesheet might still be cached in the browser.

To make sure you dont get cached contents do the following:
In Edge press F12 -> Go to  Network tab -> Check "always reload from server" (4th icon to the left) -> Reload the page

You can also inspect the  in the "elements" tab, and search for the stylesheet. You can open the stylesheet itselt and look for your new styles. This way you can see if you the correct stylesheet is being loaded.

Edit:

The styling from Bootstrap is overwriting the code because it uses more specific selectors. You can add a class to your element, and use that selector, or you prepend it like so: body `a { ... }` Here is more about specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/specificity

Comment: Hi, thanks. Its not a cache problem. I also inspected the given element and i see it does take the theme's style.css but it gets overridden by scaffolding.less...

Comment: Okay, then you need t write more specific code. The styling from Bootstrap is overwriting your code because it uses more specific selectors.You can add a class to your element, and use that selector, or you prepend it like so: `body a { ... }`

Here is more about specificity: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/specificity)

Comment: Yep, that Specificity. I'll look into that, but its strange it works in chrome and firefox...
maybe some javascript is fired when usin IE or Edge to modify styling....

Comment: Please DO NOT use `!important` in this case. It will overwrite anything else, and will just lead to more trouble in the future.

Comment: If you edits your anwser to include the Specificity, I can mark it as anwser